# dyShading of x-axis with additional limits on y-axis

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

On this simple dygraph, 2 different colours are used to highlight/shade values that either correspond to positive or negative side of the y-axis. The shaded areas will often overlap and it's hard to see the highlighted events in larger data series. I want to limit the shading to cover only half of the graph on y-axis, e.g. green shade starts above 0, and purple starts below 0.

```
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)
data1 <- xts(matrix( c(rnorm(50, mean = 3), rnorm(50, mean = -3) ) , ncol=2, nrow=50), order.by=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), by=3600, length.out = 50))

dygraph(data1) %>%
   dyShading(from = "2017-10-01 12:00:00",to = "2017-10-02 08:00:00", color = "rgba(10, 89, 4, 0.2)", axis = "x") %>%
   dyShading(from = "2017-10-02 00:00:00",to = "2017-10-02 16:00:00", color = "rgba(200, 200, 230, 0.4)", axis = "x")
```

[image]

I've tried to change the .js files from R dygraphs package to control these limits manually, but that's probably not the best idea. Can the y-axis shading limits be controlled somehow? A long workaround would be OK. That dygraph runs in Shiny app, if this changes anything.

UPDATE: Below is a demo of the desired effect with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)  
data2 <- data.frame(date=index(data1), coredata(data1))
data2 <- melt(data2, id.vars = 'date')

ggplot(data2, aes(x=date, y=value, group=variable)) +
   geom_line(aes()) + 
   geom_rect(data=data2, aes(xmin=as.POSIXct("2017-10-01 12:00:00"), xmax=as.POSIXct("2017-10-02 08:00:00"), ymin=0, ymax=7), alpha=0.005, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
   geom_rect(data=data2, aes(xmin=as.POSIXct("2017-10-02 00:00:00"), xmax=as.POSIXct("2017-10-02 16:00:00"), ymin=0, ymax=-7), alpha=0.005, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, you talk about y-axis but your example is about x-axis? which one you want to shade?

Comment: I am shading with respect to x-axis, but need additional control of limits for the y-axis, so that the height of shade in vertical direction doesn't automatically scale to canvas/window height. Is that clearer?  I've only included the example graph to show how difficult it is to discern the overlapping shades.

Comment: @DianaLog have you found a way to solve this?

Comment: @user189035 unfortunately not.